# Use of infinity norm instead of SSE for machine learning accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, error

Are there any examples or arguments in favor of using an infinity norm (or equivalent) over sum of squared errors or root mean squared error for evaluating machine learning algorithms?

Comment: Well, it makes you _really_ sensitive to outliers. But if a method has a very low max error, that's an impressive indication that it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is interesting to compare this to the support vector regression loss.

Samples that are predicted correctly within some margin are not part of the loss. Only those which exceed it. Given a margin $m$, the prediction $\hat{y}$ and the target $y$ the loss is
$$
l(y, \hat{y}) = \max((y - \hat{y})^2 - m, 0).
$$
Letting $m \rightarrow 0$ while keeping some $\sum_i l(y_i, \hat{y}_i)$ starting with a very large $m$ would then result in a similar optimisation problem.

This also highlights the practical issues: it is unlikely that it will be possible to get $m=0$, and if so you probably overfit. Also, this always concentrates on the currently worst prediction, which will make this fail if you have outliers (as mentioned by Dougal, +1).

Further insight can be gained by interpreting such an infinity loss as a Dirac assumption on the errors of the targets. We know that ML is equivalent to minimizing the KL of the empirical and the model distribution. The KL between two distributions with different support is not defined (you will take the log of some zeros), which makes me believe that this approach is not a good idea--even though it can be done without the probabilistic interpretation in mind.